# Multiple app instances, windows GDI limit

Tags: c#, gdi

Im trying to run simultaneously hundreds of instances of the same app(using C#), and after about 200 instances the GUI starts to slow down dramatically until the point that the load time of the next instance is climbing up to 20s (from 1s).

The test maching is :
xeon 5520 
12gb ram 
windows 2008 web 64 bit

at max load (200 instances) the cpu is at about 20% and ram 45%, so im sure its not a hardware issue.

I already tried configuring Session size and SharedSection in the registry of the windows but it doesnt seem to help.

I also tried to running the app in the background and also on multiple sessions (different sessions) and still the same (i though maybe it a limitation per session).

When the slowdown occures for example on one session i can login to another session and the desktops works without a problem (the first dekstop becomse unusable.)

My question is - is there a way to strip the gdi objects or maybe eliminate the use of the GUI? or is it a windows limitation?

p.s - I cant change the app since its a third pary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With 200 instances running, the constant context switching is probably hurting performance.  Context switching isn't counted in CPU load.

Edit: whoops, wrong link.

Try monitoring context switching on your system
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938606.aspx

Comment: Hi Nick, i've monitored it not sure what it means, please take a look here http://www.2shared.com/photo/5FE2sbCu/server-load.html. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's GDI - if you run out of GDI handles/resources you'll notice vast chunks of your windows failing to redraw, rather than everythign slowing down.

The most likely reason for a sudden drop in performance is that you are maxing out your RAM and thrashing your Virtual Memory as all your processes fight for CPU time. Check memory usage, and if it's high, see if you can reduce the footprint of your application. Or apply a "hardware fix" by installing more RAM. Or add Sleeps into your Apps where possible so that they aren't demanding constant timeslices from your CPU (and thus needing to be constantly paged in from VM).

Comment: Hi Jason, i did had the issue you described before tweaking the registry. regarding the ram - i did mention before that at the time of the slow down the memory usage is about 45% and the cpu is only 20% so im pretty sure its not physical hardware issue. thanks for the quick reply. other idea?

Comment: Might the app do anything non-scalable? If it doesn't expect to have 200 instances running, it is easily possible that it's doing something that interferes with itself. There could be all manner of things that wouldn't scale well, where the orignal author never imagined a scenario where 200 instances would be run simultaneously (e.g. contention for a shared resource like a file, message broadcasts to the entire group of instances, shared memory, etc).

Comment: Ultimately if you don't "own" the app being executed, there may not be a lot you can do. However, you may be able to apply small tweaks (e.g. you may be able to reduce GDI resource usage by opening all the apps offscreen, but only if the app is well enough written to avoid using resources until it needs them). You could try a process monitor to see if you can spot any hints about what's going on (e.g. Whats the hard drive usage like - Is it also 45%, or is it maxed out? There's a bottleneck, so if it's not RAM or CPU, it's may be I/O - maybe putting crucial resources on a RAMdisk might help)

Comment: Regarding the IO - its already running from a ram disk (but i like the way you think :)) and theres almost no IO. I also tries runnig the app in the background but still get the same result. i did however checked the context switching as Nick suggested but im not sure what it means, perhaps you can tell me - heres a screenshot taken when it was under full server load http://www.2shared.com/photo/5FE2sbCu/server-load.html

Comment: Sorry, I haven't looked at context switches in that respect, so can't give you any firm guidance in that direction. (But I would have thought that unless the apps are doing something rather antisocial (like forcing context switches in busy wait loops), a mere 200 processes shouldn't put the OS under any great strain). Maybe if you can post more info (e.g. about what the app is doing) someone may be able to give you more clues.